# Unwanted space between wrapping flex-items

Tags: css, flexbox

When I set flex-container height larger than what flex-items would occupy, items that wrap, have space between them. Mind you - justify-content and align-items are both set to flex-start. Here is snippet (click on **full page** after run)

```css
.flex-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
header,
main,
aside,
footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}
header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
}
main {
  width: 75%;
}
aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <header>Header Content</header>
  <main>Main content here.</main>
  <aside>Sidebar content</aside>
  <footer>Footer Content</footer>
</div>
```

[Here's the pen](https://codepen.io/galingong/pen/PVbpVE)

This can be reproduced with `flex-direction: column;` if you reversed all the properties. Is this expected behavior? If so, why? Is there a way I came around this and get something like that:

[image]

with the flex-container height set to 100vh ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer without adding extra markup, is `align-content: flex-start;` - default is `stretch`, that's why wrapping elements have extra space between them, when the flex-container's size exceeds the size of the elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

If I good understand your question - you can add following div `.wrappper` inside `flex-container`

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {margin: 0}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header,
main,
aside,
footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}
header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  
}
main {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header Content</header>
  <main>Main content here.</main>
  <aside>Sidebar content</aside>
  <footer>Footer Content</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explanation what previous solution doesn't wokrs: because the height of your flex items was set to 1rem+font size, and the `align-items: flex-start;` was set so flex not change items height but put them on proper place (flex-start). But if you would use `align-items: streth;` then flex will stretch elements. Because you want to have 100vh for .flex-container, we need to use wrapper which was not stretched to full height of container because container has still `align-items: flex-start;`. And that wrapper height is sum of his chidren height without extra space.

Comment: Thank you, that would indeed remove the spacing, but all it does, is make the flex-children occupy the unwanted space. I'd like that space to collapse and flex-items to stay the same height as they normally would outside a flexbox.

Comment: @galingong Are you able to draw some picture and update your question by including it?   Because form me Is hard to understand what you need

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear. I'd like to achieve this: [Image](https://i.ibb.co/KsLGHKx/Screenshot-4.png) with the flex-container height set to 100vh.

Comment: @galingong I update answer (after run click on "full page")

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted, it works. But I still don't understand, why it spaced the elements originally.